# MongoDB distinct- returns only matched array elements

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to fetch distinct tags from array for auto-complete module. The collection format is:

```js
{
  tags:["apple","mango","apple-pie"]
},
{
  tags: ["man","lemon","lemon-lite"]
}
```

Now, I am interested in getting distinct tags, with prefix q.

The query that I triggered is:

```js
db.portfolio.distinct("tags",{"tags":/app/});
```

However, this query returned entire array:
`["apple","mango","apple-pie"]`.

My requirement is: `["apple", "apple-pie"]`.

How can I modify my query to get desired result?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to the issue you were facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `aggregation`.

1. You `$unwind` the `tags` array.
2. You `$match` those tags you are looking for according to the regular expression given.
3. You `$group` the tags into a set using `$addToSet`.

The code looks something like this:

```js
> db.portfolio.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$match": { "tags": /app/ }},
    { "$group":
        {
            "_id": null,
            "tags": { "$addToSet": "$tags" }
        }
    }
]);
{ "_id" : null, "tags" : [ "apple-pie", "apple" ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with distinct because query will return documents containing matching tags(/app/) which mean there will be non matching tags as well. distinct gets a distinct set from all these tags.
So you will have to filter the returning array again( using regex /app/)